# Peaches, plums, and brown rot

Tags: fungus

According to http://www.ent.uga.edu/peach/peachhbk/fungal/brownrot.pdf

> Wild plum thickets are an important source of spores for both primary and secondary infections. Wild plums bloom
>   before and during peach bloom, and the fruit mature continuously from early to late in the season, providing a
>   continuing source of inoculum. Removal of wild plums adjacent to a peach orchard is an important sanitation
>   procedure.

Unfortunately, I have lots of wild plums which are providing privacy for a place which I sometimes have fires.  I waited 5 years for these plums to get tall and thick enough to provide this cover, now I learn I have to remove them if I'm ever to expect a decent peach harvest.

Is there anything economical enough to spray on lots of trees for the sake of a few peach trees?  And that isn't going to kill my fish and frogs in the pond I have 500ft downhill from the trees?

I don't expect to ever be rid of the fungus, I just want to make it as uncomfortable for the fungus as I can and without spending much or going to much effort.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything particularly effective to prevent brown rot, but, if you are only growing the wild plum as cover, is there a possibility you can coppice or pollard them before the fruit forms on a yearly basis? It's the fruits that get brown rot, so if you are able to stop fruits forming, that will solve the problem.

UPDATE: Brown rot is a term applied specifically to rotting of fruits on trees, and has nothing to do with any fungal growths occurring in other parts of the tree. The cause of that will be different, so identifying quite what it is could be very helpful, because with any luck, it might be something treatable rather than a sign of decay or serious problem in your trees.

Comment: Sorry Bamboo, for some reason I didn't know anyone had answered this. I had actually come to delete the question, figuring it would never be answered. All I can think to do is increase the health of the trees. Actually, the rot seems to affect the stems of the peach trees as well, or maybe its a rot by another name cohabitating with brown rot, idk. One thing is sure, I find peaches one of the most challenging fruit trees to grow in the "peach state".